# WPF: Three different grids are bound to Visibility-Property, is there more efficient way?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Since hours, I am stuck with following problem:

I am new to WPF, especially to MVVM. I have three different classes (`Car`, `Motorcycle`, `Truck`) with different properties. You can select the vehicle in a `Combobox`.
Here an example of my `Car`-Class:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Axes { get; set; }
    public int Seats { get; set; }
    public int Doors { get; set; }
    public VehicleProperties.Car.Type Type { get; set; }
    public int MaxWeight { get; set; }
    public Fuel Fuel { get; set; }
    public double ConsumptionPer100km { get; set; }
    public bool Childseat { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int FirstRegistration { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public bool Tempomat { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
    public int PollutionClass { get; set; }
    public int EnvironmentalBadge { get; set; }
}
```

`Motorcycle`-Class:

```
public class Motorcycle
{
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public Fuel Fuel { get; set; }
    public VehicleProperties.Motorcycle.Type Type { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public int FirstRegistration { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public DriveType DriveType { get; set; }
    public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }
    public int CubicCapacity { get; set; }
    public int PollutionClass { get; set; }
    public Brush Color { get; set; }
    public int ConsumptionPer100km { get; set; }
}
```

`Truck`-Class:

```
public class Truck
{
    public VehicleProperties.Truck.Type Type { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Mileage { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public Fuel Fuel { get; set; }
    public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }
    public int Axes { get; set; }
    public int MaxWeight { get; set; }
    public bool Tempomat { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
    public int PollutionClass { get; set; }
    public string WheelFormula { get; set; }
    public int ConsumptionBadge { get; set; }
}
```

I have to create a window where you can create a new vehicle, depending on the vehicle you chose. I firstly thought about looking getting the properties of the class and check with a `Markup-Extension` in XAML dynamically for the `DataType`, but it did not work because the output was always a `string`. Most important: even if I got it to work, how will I bind them dynamically?

Now, I am designing 3 grids for each class, binding them to variables and I have bound the `Visibility`-Property to three `bool`s. Is there a more efficient solution? I feel like this is not the right way to do this.

Comment: can you show the classes ``Motorcycle`` an ``Truck`` also? I'm pretty sure there will be common properties which you can pack in a base class (or Interface) . Then you might build a UserControl for each. Probably you will be able to split into a base-data-control for the common base class/Interface and a 3 special Usercontrols, then you could use a datatemplateselector based on your Type (``Car``, ``Truck``, ``Motorcycle``)

Comment: Instead of answering yourself, edit the question :-)

Comment: @dba Okay, i did it.

Comment: Your comoboBox allows to select vehicles or vehicle categories? Then according to the picked category you want to show a window to create a new vehicle? How does your view look like?

Comment: @BionicCode No, in the `ComboBox`, you can choose between `Car`, `Motorcycle` and `Truck` and in the current version, I have three grids in the same View. For example, if you choose `Car` (SelectedIndex = 0), I switch the `Car`-`Grid` to Visible and the other two `Grid`s to `Collapsed`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the different views using a `DataTemplate` for each vehicle type e.g., `Car`.
The idea is to show the `DataTemplate` based on the selected vehicle data type. Since you define each `DataTemplate` as implicite template (without the x:Key directive), the templates will be applied automatically (by data type).

In the following example the selected data type is exposed as `MainViewModel.NewVehicle` property which binds to a `ContentControl`. The `ContentControl` will then automatically apply the appropriate `DataTemplate`. The `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` is the current data type like `Car`. This why you can bind the UI elements of the template easily to the new instance.

Whenever you select a category from the `ComboBox`, the `MainViewModel` will create a new empty instance of the selected vehicle type and assign it to `MainViewModel.NewVehicle` propoerty. After you are done with editing the new vehicle via the UI provided by the `DataTemplate`, you can handle the finished `MainViewModel.NewVehicle`.

The interfcace `IVehicleProvider` are meant to eliminate a `switch` or multiple `if` to determine the actual vehicle type to create. It is implemented by the IVehicle interface which must be implemented by every vehicle type.

The key parts of the solution is the use of `DataTemplate` (see [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)) in order to create the three individual edit views and the `IVehicleProvider` to eliminate the type switch.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Car}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding VehicleType}" Background="Green" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MotoryCycle}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding VehicleType}" Background="Yellow" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Truck}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding VehicleType}" Background="Red" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding VehicleCategories}" 
              DisplayMemberPath="VehicleType" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVehicleProvider}" />

    <!-- Display the DataTemplate of the current type returned by NewVehicle -->
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding NewVehicle}"  />
  <StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public MainViewModel()
  {
    this.VehicleCategories = new List<IVehicle>
    {
      new Car(),
      new Truck(),
      new MotoryCycle()
    };
  }

  private void OnSelectedvehicleCategoryChanged()
    => this.NewVehicle = this.SelectedVehicleCategoryProvider.CreateEmpty();

  public List<IVehicle> VehicleCategories { get; }

  // The new vehicle, ready for edit in a view provided by a DataTemplate.
  private IVehicle newVehicle;
  public IVehicle NewVehicle
  {
    get => this.newVehicle;
    set
    {
      this.newVehicle = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private IVehicleProvider selectedVehicleCategoryProvider;
  public IVehicleProvider SelectedVehicleCategoryProvider
  {
    get => this.selectedVehicleCategory;
    set
    {
      this.selectedVehicleCategory = value;
      OnSelectedvehicleCategoryChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**VehicleType.cs**

```
public enum VehicleType
{
  Default = 0, 
  Car, 
  Truck, 
  Motorcycle
}
```

**IVehicle.cs**

```
public interface IVehicle : IVehicleProvider
{
  VehicleType VehicleType { get; }
}
```

**IVehicleProvider.cs**

```
public interface IVehicleProvider
{
  IVehicle CreateEmpty();
}
```

**Car.cs**

```
public class Car : IVehicle
{
  public VehicleType VehicleType => VehicleType.Car;

  public IVehicle CreateEmpty() => new Car();

  // Properties of Car
}
```

**Truck.cs**

```
public class Truck : IVehicle
{
  public VehicleType VehicleType => VehicleType.Truck;
  public IVehicle CreateEmpty() => new Truck();

  // Properties of Truck
}
```

**MotoryCycle.cs**

```
public class MotoryCycle : IVehicle
{
  public VehicleType VehicleType => VehicleType.Motorcycle;
  public IVehicle CreateEmpty() => new MotoryCycle();

  // Properties of MotoryCycle
}
```